# no such file to load -- gollum

Tags: rubygems, gollum-wiki

I've been trying stubbornly to install gollum behind a firewall, downloading all dependency gems until gollum installed without error or --force. Now that it is installed, I get the following error:

```
~/docs$ gollum
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- gollum (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gollum-2.4.11/bin/gollum:18
        from /usr/local/bin/gollum:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/gollum:19
```

Could someone walk me through how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

As so often, immediately after posting the question I tried one more thing: Downloading the gollum gem itself instead of building it from master. And it was good.